# Box around an algorithm that spans two columns

Tags: algorithmic, box

Consider the following code, that provides a box around an algorithm. However, it does not work when the algorithm needs to span both columns in a double column article. To be specific, when I use `\begin{figure*}` instead of `\begin{figure}` in the following code in order to span the algorithm into both columns, the algorithm still spans a single column only.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newsavebox{\ieeealgbox}
\newenvironment{boxedalgorithmic}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\ieeealgbox}
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
   \begin{algorithmic}}
  {\end{algorithmic}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}\noindent\fbox{\usebox{\ieeealgbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{boxedalgorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\IF{$y = 0$}
\STATE Some statement
\ENDIF
\end{boxedalgorithmic}
\caption{aaa}
\label{aaa}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I don't want to break the algorithm, just want it to span two columns, and have a box around it. Take a look at the picture below: fig-7 is what I get if I use `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` and use `\begin{algorithmic}...\end{algorithmic}` instead of `\begin{boxedalgorithmic}...\end{boxedalgorithmic}`. This one spans two columns, but I want a box around it. When I use both `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` and `\begin{boxedalgorithmic}...\end{boxedalgorithmic}`, the algorithm gets a box around it, but it still stays in a single column.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to break the algorithm - just want it two span two columns. Have a look at my edited question.

Comment: Try with `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}`

Comment: I did try `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` (as I have stated in the question). This does not solve the problem - the algorithm still stays in one column. I guess we need to do something with the `boxedalgorithmic` environment.

Comment: You just need to replace \columnwidth with \linewidth.  Evidently figure* does not reset \columnwidth.  BTW, it would have helped if the example algorithm did not give errors.

Comment: Corrected the example algorithm - thanks. Also, replacing \columnwidth with \linewidth worked. Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
...
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{aaa}
\label{aaa}
\end{algorithm*}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```